# O que expressa o uso de "teu" / "tua" no Brasil?

Tags: português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

Às vezes a palavra *"seu" / "sua"* está substituída com *"teu" / "tua"* no Brasil.

Por exemplo:

> **Seu** cabelo ta lindo!

vs.

> **Teu** cabelo ta lindo!

A Wikipédia menciona o uso como "fora da norma", mas nada explica sobre um contexto ou significado: [Portuguese Personal Pronouns (ingles)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_personal_pronouns#In_Brazilian_Portuguese)

Faz sentido em regiões do Brasil onde a forma *"tu"* é mais comum, mas estou curioso sobre o uso fora disso, tipo assim:

> However, even in some of the regions where "você" is the prevailing pronoun, the object pronoun te and ti and the possessive pronoun teu/tua are quite common...
>   -- Wikipédia

**Por que as pessoas quem normalmente usam *"seu" / "sua"* as vezes mudam pela outra forma?**

**O que expressa essa substituição?**

Comment: Só para constar na pergunta... Em Portugal usamos o teu/tua regularmente no dia-a-dia. Usamos o seu/sua no caso de estarmos a falar para, por exemplo, o nosso chefe. 
Cá usamos teu/tua como vocês usam seu/sua.

Comment: Sua escrita está muito boa! Precisou de muita ajuda de um tradutor para escrever essa pergunta ou já está se virando sozinho?

Comment: Hahah muito obrigado @Math, eu escrevi isso sem tradutor sim, mas o Lucas ajudou com as correções - valeu @LucasMotta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **O que expressa o uso de “teu” / “tua” no Brasil?**

**Teu/tua** são os pronomes possessivos da segunda pessoa do singular, na norma culta. **Seu/sua** são pronomes possessivos da terceira pessoa do singular.
Porém no português do Brasil (em algumas regiões) é muito comum usarem, erroneamente, o pronome **seu** como se fosse da segunda pessoa.

- **O que expressa essa substituição?**

Em algumas regiões, onde é mais comum o uso de **teu/tua**, usa-se **seu/sua** para se tratar *formalmente*. 
Ex.:

> O senhor pode me mostrar **seu** documento?

De qualquer forma, **seu/sua** são pronomes da terceira pessoa e seu emprego como se fossem da segunda pessoa é errado (mesmo sendo tão comum).

**EDIT:** Origem do "pronome você"

**Você** é forma evoluída (transformada) do pronome de tratamento *vossa mercê*, assim: **vossa mercê** virou **vossemecê**, que virou **vosmecê**, até virar **você**.

Nós usamos **você** como pronome pessoal da segunda pessoal, entretanto, em razão da origem, **você** é pronome de tratamento – da mesma forma que vossa excelência, vossa senhoria, vossa majestade, etc. E todos os pronomes de tratamento são de terceira pessoa, por isso é tão comum usar **seu/sua** como se fossem da segunda pessoa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta informativa @Jéferson. Por favor - qual sua opinião sobre a outra posibilidade - tem algum significado particular quando gente que normalmente usa seu/sua usa teu/tua? É o que me interessava primeiramente :)

Comment: Na verdade, não. Eu acho eles fazem meio que uma mistura dos dois pronomes.

Comment: Fiquei confuso. Talvez por ser português. O Jéferson defende que no Brasil é incorreto (ainda que comum) dizer "Onde você conheceu sua esposa?" e que é correto dizer "Onde você conheceu tua esposa?"

Comment: É incorreto misturar segunda e terceira pessoa. Mas o uso da terceira pessoa ocorre como foi explicado pelo uso de "você", mesmo que oculto na frase. "Onde estão suas chaves?". A não ser no Rio Grande do Sul onde se faz mistura da segunda e terceira pessoa de forma peculiar, no restante do país não é incorreto usar a terceira pessoa no lugar da segunda. A segunda pessoa é vista como coisa antiga (principalmente a 2 do plural), e usada para evitar ambiguidades.