# When to use "tua" and "sua"?

Tags: determinantes-possessivos

When to use *tua* and *sua*? (Quando usar *tua* e *sua*?)

Eg.:

> - Esta é sua casa?
> - Esta é tua casa?

Eg.:

> - Seu carro está na garagem.
> - Teu carro está na garagem.

When should I use *tua* instead of *sua*? Is there a difference between the two in formulating sentences? (Quando devo usar *tua* ao invés de *tua*? Há diferença entre elas na formulação de frases?)

Comment: Related: [O que expressa o uso de “teu” / “tua” no Brasil?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/440/o-que-expressa-o-uso-de-teu-tua-no-brasil)

Comment: @MichalMau Considera uma duplicata? O que acha?

Comment: @E_net4 não vou deletar pois serve de referencia pra pesquisas, mas também marquei como duplicata

Comment: Na realidade, acabei de levantar o voto para fechar. A outra pergunta é específica ao português do Brasil, enquanto que esta parece ser mais genérica.

Comment: @E_net4 vou concordar com teu último argumento, de inicio pensei que "tua" era algo do Brasil, mas se diz isto então é porque estou enganado... Levantei o meu voto também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, as duas formas podem ser usadas no português de Portugal, embora de maneira diferente e com motivos diferentes.

Comment: Acho que a minha pergunta é mais specifica, mas a única resposta que ela recebou até agora é tão génerica que poderia ser mais adequada aquí.

Comment: Concordo com vocês. Melhor deixar elas separadas e vamos ver como andam. A gente sempre pode marcar como duplicatas mais tarde...

Comment: Talvez: “É esta a tua casa?”

Comment: @tchrist Faz sentido.

Comment: @MichalMau Eu respondi nesta pergunta e não na outra precisamente por esta pergunta ser mais geral. Espero que responda ao que querias saber.

Answer (score 6):

**PORTUGUESE** (**In English below**)

Na norma culta, usam-se os pronomes possessivos **teu/tua** quando se trata o interlocutor por **tu**, e usa-se **seu/sua** quando se trata o interlocutor por um pronome de tratamento como **você, a senhora, o menino, Vossa Excelência, etc.** Os pronomes possessivos **seu** e **sua** são da terceira pessoa (ele, ela, eles, elas), mas quando se usa um [pronome de tratamento](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf46.php) toda a concordância verbal e pronominal é com a terceira pessoa do singular.

Exemplos com tratamento por **tu** e por **você**. Qualquer outro pronome de tratamento seria igual ao exemplo de *você*.

> **Tu** vais à praia? Levas-me con**tigo**? Olha, deixaste cair o **teu** lenço. Vou dar-**te** isto.
>
> **Você** vai à praia? Leva-me con**sigo**? Olhe, deixou cair o **seu** lenço. Vou dar-**lhe** isto.

Repito que isto é a norma culta. No Brasil ouve-se a algumas pessoas usar o *teu/tua* com *você*, como por exemplo na canção [Meu Eu Em Voçê](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzjSLwz4dgU).

Ora até agora abordamos exclusivamente a questão gramatical. Uma questão mais complicada é em que situações tratar uma pessoa por **tu**, **você**, ou por **senhor(a)**. [Este assunto foi tratado aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/205/when-to-use-o-senhor?lq=1), e eu vou dar apenas uma ideia muito geral. Na maior parte do Brasil o **tu** é raro na norma culta,e, como eu sou português, não sei como é que as pessoas reagiriam se alguém as tratasse por *tu*.* Uma exceção é a Amazónia, onde **tu** é muito usado. O **você** é mais familiar e **senhor(a)** mais cerimonioso, mas esta distinção não tem implicações no uso dos possessivos. Em Portugal **tu** é o tratamento informal usado praticamente universalmente entre jovens, mesmo que desconhecidos, amigos, e família; **senhor(a)** é o mais cerimonioso; e **você** fica algures no meio.

*Nota: aqui na comunidade, eu trato toda a gente por tu, e ainda ninguém me repreendeu.

**ENGLISH**

In Standard Language **teu/tua** are used when you address your conversation partner by **tu**; **seu/sua** are used if you address them by an [addressing pronoun](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf46.php) such as **você, a senhora, o menino, Vossa Excelência, etc.** **Seu** and **sua** are third-person possessive pronouns, but when you use an addressing pronoun verbs and pronouns are used as if with the third-person singular.

Here are some example of how pronouns vary depending on whether you address someone by by **tu** or by **você**. For any other addressing pronoun the examples would be just like with *você*.

> **Tu** vais à praia? Levas-me con**tigo**? Olha, deixaste cair o **teu** lenço. Vou dar-**te** isto.
>
> **Você** vai à praia? Leva-me con**sigo**? Olhe, deixou cair o **seu** lenço. Vou dar-**lhe** isto.

I insist: this is what happens in Standard Language. In Brazil some people say *teu/tua* while addressing someone by *você*, as in the song [Meu Eu em Você](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzjSLwz4dgU)

So far we have only discussed grammar. Whether to address someone by **tu, você**, or **senhor(a)** is a lot more complicated. [This is addressed in this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/205/when-to-use-o-senhor?lq=1), and I’ll convey a general idea only. In Brazil **tu** is rare in Standard Language, and, as I am Portuguese, I am not sure how people would react if I addressed them by *tu*.* The Amazon region is an exception: **tu** is commonly used there. **Você** is more informal and **senhor(a)** more deferential, but this difference has no implication on the choice of possessive pronouns. In Portugal **tu** is a near universal form of address among young people (even if they do not know each other), friends and relatives; **senhor(a)** is more deferential; **você** lies somewhere in between.

*Note: I use **tu** with everybody in this community, and haven’t been reprimanded so far.

Comment: Note: Tu, Teu, Tua are most commom in some Brasil states (Pernambuco and Rio Grande do Sul)

Comment: Obrigado pela informação. Vou incorporar na resposta.

Answer (score 5):

### Tua - informal

`Tua` is the informal everyday way to say **you**.  There is no respect attached to the word, unlike `sua`.  This is the you one would use with friends, taxi drivers, clerks, and so on... people with whom you talk everyday.  Even some professors would rather tua be used, unless they're the over-zealous kind that make you call them Dr. Whoever III

The verb for this is [**tutear**](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/tutear%20_1061155.html)

> Eu gosto da tua casa

### Sua - formal

This one shows respect to whom you are talking.  Speaking to people like the president, a professor, a doctor, a coveted celebrity, and pretty much anyone that you hold superior to yourself and want to convey that respect to.

> Eu gosto da sua casa

Comment: Your answer does not reflect usage in Brazil at all, and reflects usage in Portugal only approximately. People will usually use *seu/sua* with taxi drivers, clerks, etc., especially if they don't known them.