# Seu vs dele for Possessions

Tags: português-europeu, pronomes, português-brasileiro

There seem to be two ways of expressing someone's property:

*Determiner + Noun*, for example:

> A sua camisa - His (or her) shirt.

*Noun + Preposition-Pronoun*:

> A camisa dele  - His shirt

It seems that both of these forms are equally legal. Therefore, which form do I use and when? Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: Mr Chasi: please note that I rewrote my answer.

Comment: "(A) sua camisa" translates to "Your shirt" and is common to ommit the article

Comment: sua/seu means two things: his OR her AND your. That's your confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that the possessive pronouns don't necessarily mean "possession of property", but I'll use terms such as "posessor" henceforth.

If you're referring to an interlocutor that you're addressing in the third person, then there's no choice: you have to use ***seu***, not ***dele***. You could also use *do senhor*, *da professora*, etc. (but not *de você*!, at least in Portugal). The chosen form depends on the emphasis, as explained below for *seu*/*dele*, though in this case the difference is even more marked.

Otherwise, the rule of thumb is that if the property belongs to the subject, you use `seu`, otherwise you use `dele`.

### Not referring to the grammatical subject

Take this example:

> (1) Hoje pus a lavar a camisa dele.

If we reformulate it with *sua*:

> (2) Hoje pus a lavar a sua camisa.

we would still have a valid sentence, but it sounds affected, and hardly anyone would say it (though they could write it). In this sense, it is more formal, but you could (and some people do, as Jacinto mentions in his answer) just write it off as bad style. Sentence (2) has also has the problem that, at least in theory, it could be referring to an interlocutor addressed in the 3rd person.

Note that this contrasts with the use of *si* and *consigo*, which can **only** refer 1) either to the subject or 2) in Portugal, to an interlocutor addressed in the 3rd person.

### Referring to the grammatical subject

The case where the possessor **is** the grammatical subject is not as clear-cut. In general, you should use *seu*, except that:

1. Perhaps because *dele* is positioned in a more prominent position in the sentence, it can mark the possession more strongly (e.g. to introduce a contrast), rather than merely identifying the object through his possessor. The same effect can be had by stressing *seu* and an even bigger one by adding *mesmo*/*próprio*. Nevertheless, if the owner of the object can be inferred, then the pronoun can be omitted altogether:

   > (3) Hoje o João trouxe o carro. [he didn't take the bus, without more, the car is presumably his]
   >   (4) Hoje o João trouxe o seu carro. [he didn't take the bus and we know for sure the car is his]
   >   (5) Hoje o João trouxe o seu próprio carro. [constrast with else's]
   >   (6) Hoje o João trouxe o carro dele. [both are possible, (5) is favored]
2. If there is an ambiguity and *seu* can refer to an interlocutor addressed in the 3rd person, use *dele*. This avoids these exchanges:

   > (7) A: - O João levou o seu carro de serviço.
   >       B: - O meu?!
   >       A: - Não, o dele.
3. Because *seu* agrees only with the noun, and not the owner, there can sometimes be ambiguities that wouldn't exist with *dele*, especially in writing, where *seu* is common to refer to persons other than the speaker:

   > (8) O João sentou-se com a Joana e discutiu os seus planos.

   If (8) was a written sentence, I would question whether *seus* refers to João's plan, Joana's or both. A better sentence would therefore be:

   > (9) O João sentou-se com a Joana e discutiu os planos dele/dela/deles.

   This ambiguity applies more to *written* speech though. If these utterances were spoken:

   > (10) O João senta-se ao lado do Carlos. Está agora a ler os seus [do João] apontamentos.
   >   (11) O João senta-se ao lado do Carlos. Está agora a ler os apontamentos dele [ambiguous, but most likely Carlos'].

   It would be difficult to interpret (10) as referring to Carlos' notes.

There are also reasons **not** to use *dele*:

1. It cannot be used at all if it refers to an indefinite pronoun and using *dele* would force you to choose a sex for the possessor*:

   > (12) Há cem anos atrás, a maior parte das pessoas teria negado, com violência e indignação, que sentisse sequer o desejo de fazer amor com alguém que não fosse o seu cônjuge.

   If you used *dele* or *dela*, you would be changing the meaning of the sentence by restricting it to one sex.

   However, in (13) *seu trabalho* can be replaced with *trabalho dele* because we know that Bill Watterson is a man:

   > (13) Watterson era, apenas, alguém que prezava muito o seu trabalho e que não olhava a banda desenhada como um mero entretenimento.

   But it would arguably be stylistically inferior, especially in writing.
2. If *dele* is ambiguous because there's a third person it could refer to, you should avoid it and use *seu*. For instance, don't use (11) to convey the meaning of (10).
3. Because of its different position in the sentence, *dele* can also get quite far from the noun it's qualifying and therefore make the sentence awkward. In those cases, if *dele* refers to the subject, you should definitely take the option of replacing it with *seu*. Taking Jacinto's example: you should replace (14) with (15):

   > (14) O João trouxe a camisa às riscas azuis e brancas dele!
   >   (15) O João trouxe a sua camisa às riscas azuis e brancas!

Outside of these cases, the choice between the two to refer to the subject is up to the speaker. Generally (an there will be exceptions!), using *seu* sounds more polished and natural, so I would go with that, especially in writing.

### Using both

As more of a curiosity, you can also use both *seu* and *dele* for emphasis, though this is very rare, at least in Portugal. [Cunha & Cintra's grammar](https://books.google.nl/books/about/?id=ct2bmQEACAAJ) gives this example:

> (16) Montaigne explica pelo seu modo dele a variedade deste livro. (Machado de Assis, OC, II, 556)

<sub>* Examples from [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/).</sub>

Comment: Your rule of thumb does not convince me. "Hoje ele trouxe a camisa dele,"  meaning his own shirt, is fine. And "ele trouxe a camisa dela com flores" sounds as bad as your own example, even though the shirt does not belongs to the subject.

Comment: @Jacinto Your second example doesn't sound good because of the order: "Hoje ele trouxe a camisa com flores dela" is how I would say it. As to the other point, I never said that "Hoje ele trouxe a camisa dele" is wrong, just that it's stylistically inferior and much worse if there is more than one possible referent.

Comment: Same with your example: "ele trouxe a camisa com flores dele" sounds just as good as "ele trouxe a camisa com flores dela". I guess we don't have the same notions of style.

Comment: @Jacinto You're right, I fixed the example. I don't think it changes anything though, "hoje ele trouxe a sua camisa com flores" still sounds better than "hoje ele trouxe a camisa com flores dele" or "hoje trouxe a camisa com flores dele" (just to rule out the possibility that what makes it sound bad is the repeated "ele").

Comment: To me what makes it sound worse, but this applies to own object as to someone else's, is the length of the thing: "Ele trouxe a camisa às riscas azuis e brancas dela!"

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo e decidi reformular a resposta.

Comment: Parece-em que a tua regra do *seu* refere-se ao sujeito tem aplicação limitada, como mostra o teu exemplo 8; *dele* referir-se ao outro, para mim, não é verdade; com dois *eles* fica normalmente ambíguo. Na fala, eu uso *dele* exceto em contextos especiais. Seu eu fosse ter com a Carla, mãe do Nuno, diria: "Olá Carla, o Nuno pede-te para me dares aquela camisa dele às riscas azuis e brancas." Se eu tratasse a Carla por você teria que ser assim, e eu não mudo por a tratar por tu. O MEC critica o *seu* mesmo quando este se refere ao sujeito. E tu queres tirar-me o recorde da resposta mais longa!

Comment: @Jacinto Claro que tem aplicação limitada, daí eu qualificar a afirmação (que nunca me atrevi a chamar de "regra", hás de reparar) em pormenor a seguir. Quando à tua frase, ela não soa bem com _sua camisa_ porque o sujeito da oração reduzida é _tu_. Compara: "Olá Carla, o Nuno pediu-te para tu o deixares trazer aquela sua camisa às riscas azuis e brancas". Aqui "seu" já se refere ao sujeito da oração reduzida "(ele) trazer aquela sua camisa às riscas azuis e brancas" e a frase é perfeita, ainda que "dele" soe praticamente tão bem aqui.

Comment: Eu digo, e creio que toda a gente, "Olá Carla, como *está*? O Nuno precisa daquela camisa dele azul às riscas;" "Olá Carla, como *estás*? O Nuno precisa daquela camisa dele azul às riscas." Quando me imagino a falar com alguém que conheço, não digo "sua camisa"; digo "camisa dele." As frases parecem uma coisa quando escritas; parecem outra quando te imaginas realmente a dizê-las a alguém.

Comment: @Jacinto Tudo bem, mas nada disso contraria o que está escrito nesta resposta, apenas diz que há frases em que "dele" é preferível na oralidade. Mas é igualmente fácil arranjar frases em que "seu" é mais natural como "ele tem à sua frente muitos desafios". Será mais uma questão de preferência pessoal, com mais tendência para "seu" na escrita.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference (perverse) between ptPT and ptBR concerning the use of **"seu/sua"** and **"dele/dela"**.  **In Brazil we hardly ever use "seu/sua" for the third person singular.** Instead, we use "dele/dela". We use "seu/sua" for the Brazilian second person singular "você", which requires verbal agreement in the third person singular.  This can create confusion if you are not aware of this difference in usage. When I took my eldest daughter to Portugal a few years ago, a Portuguese relative of mine turned to her and said:
- "Veja este vestido. A Maria comprou um igual para a sua irmã".  My daughter immediately displayed a question mark on her face and asked: "pra quem???", and I had to explain: "para a irmã dela".
In Brazil, if you say "Alvaro foi com o seu carro", the listener will assume Alvaro went for a drive in the listener's car. To avoid a misunderstanding you would have to say "Alvaro foi com o carro dele".

- In ptPT - "Ela estava abraçando o seu marido"
- In ptBR - "Ela estava abraçando o marido dela."
- In ptBR - "Ela estava abraçando o seu marido", is likely to raise Cain.

To answer your question, in order to avoid confusion, use "dele/dela" in Brazil. In Portugal, our friends here can tell you when to use which.

**Addendum** - I don't mean to say that "seu/sua" is never used in Brazil. You will certainly hear it in some literate circles, but that's unusual. In the written language you will find it more often but still "dele/dela" prevails.

Comment: Centauros "Ela estava abraçando o seu marido" não se usa em pt_PT no máximo "Ela abraçou o seu marido." e mesmo assim prefiro "Ela abraçou o marido." ou "Ela abraçou o marido dela."

Comment: "Ela abraçou o seu marido." pode dar ideia que foi o marido da ouvinte.

Comment: @centaurus The issue you raise is equally valid in Portugal when *você* or other *pronome de tratamento* is used.

Comment: Bom saber. O teu exemplo é que não é facto muito bom porque aí o mais comum é omitir o pronome. Nem "seu" nem "dela" me soam bem.

Comment: @Artefacto Concordo, o mais comum nos dois exemplos que dei é omitir o pronome.  Mas eu precisava de exemplos e foi o que me ocorreu.

Comment: Acho que uma exceção talvez seja *cada*, como em «cada um pegue o seu lápis e vamos para a quadra.» ou «cada homem vestia (o) seu melhor paletó». Pelo menos, pra mim é comum, não sei se é o mesmo pra ti.

Answer (score 6):

**Seu, sua, seus, suas**, agree in gender and number with the thing possessed, but the possessor could be *ele, ela, eles, elas*, or the person you talking to if you’re addressing them by *você, o senhor*, or other [*pronome de tratamento*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/when-to-use-tua-and-sua/1159#1159). **Dele, dela, deles, delas**, agree only with the possessor (*ele*, etc., but not *você*, etc.), so it is often unambiguous where *seu*, etc. would be ambiguous.

If you’re addressing, say Sr. Silva, by você or other *pronome de tratamento*, one would interpret *seu* as Sr. Silva’s, unless context makes it clear it is otherwise. Take the examples:

> (a) Bom dia Sr. Silva, estive a falar com o João acerca do seu problema.
>   (b) Bom dia Sr. Silva, estive a falar com o João acerca do problema dele.

In (a) we mean Sr. Silva’s problem; in (b) João’s problem.

From now on assume you’re addressing the person you’re talking to by *tu*, so we can more easily discuss other uses of *seu*. When I imagine myself talking to a friend, I’ll use *dele* rather than *seu* in most contexts. So, yes, in many contexts *seu* will sound somewhat formal, whereas *dele* never does:

> (c) A Maria levou-me ontem à terra dela.
>   (d) O João esteve a contar-me os problemas dele.
>   (e) Não precisas de ir buscar a Ana. Ela vem no carro dela.

When the context makes it clear whom the thing we’re talking about belongs to, we typically use neither *seu* nor *dele*:

> (f) A Ana foi jantar fora com a irmã. A irmã sujou a camisa com vinho.
>   (g) O Pedro perdeu as chaves do carro. Teve que pedir boleia à namorada.

It is clear we’re talking of Ana’s sister, her sister’s shirt, Pedro’s car, and his girlfriend. These also sound more natural than the alternatives with *seu* or *dele*. And in (f) I would think *camisa dela* would be the sister’s shirt, but wouldn’t be completely sure.

*Seu* is the only option with indefinite pronouns:

> (h) Cada um vem no seu carro.
>   (i) Ninguém revelou a sua intenção.
>   (j) Toda a gente quer o melhor para os seus filhos.
>   (k) Todos têm que cumprir as suas obrigações.
>   (l) Todo o ofício tem o seu saber. (Every trade/craft has its own know-how.)

You could drop *seus* in (j) though. If we use a *pronome de tratamento*, as with Sr. Silva, (i) and (j) would be ambiguous: we could be talking of Sr. Silva’s intention and children. To make clear that is not the case, we could say:

> (i1) Falei com o pessoal, Sr. Silva, mas ninguém revelou a respetiva intenção.
>   (j1) Claro, Sr. Silva, toda a gente quer o melhor para os seus próprios filhos.
>   (j2) Claro, Sr. Silva, toda a gente quer o melhor para os filhos.

In writing and formal speech *seu* is used more extensively than in informal spoken language. [Some writers though hate the use of *seu* when *dele* would do](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/seu-ou-meu-ou-dele/2054).

Comment: Se bem percebo, o argumento é que "seu" é preterido em favor de "dele" e que a única diferença é de registo. Não fazes qualquer menção a "seu" se referir ao sujeito exceto implicitamente no contexto das frases h)-k). Inclusive, nos exemplos c)-e), "dele" refere-se sempre ao sujeito. Mas o argumento de que "seu" se refere preferencialmente ao sujeito é distinto do argumento que "dele" tende a não ser usado quando se refere ao sujeito.

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu acho que, não obstante as tuas frases, o 2o argumento é ainda válido. Em 1o lugar, d) soa melhor com "seu", a não que ser que estivesses a contrastar com os problemas doutra pessoa (vê a minha resposta editada). c) fica melhor com "dela", mas isso é explicado por "terra dele/dela" ser um grupo coeso. e) tem uma explicação semelhante a d). Estás a contrastar o carro dela com o carro do interlocutor e por isso "dela" soa melhor que "seu".